# Play blob stream from MediaRecorder?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, audio-streaming, web-audio-api, javascript-audio-api

I want to play a stream of audio blobs that came from a MediaRecorder
I have a **website** containing this piece of javascript angular code:

[image]
This is a MediaRecorder of type https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder

[image]

This sends the data from the MediaRecorder in 'audio/webm' format to the server

**Server:**

[image]

All this does is relay the blobs coming in from the MediaRecorder to all the connected clients

**Apps (Connected clients)**

[image]

This console logs:

[image]

And:

[image]

How can I play this audio blob stream on the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved this one some time ago by adding an encoding to the ByteArrays which were being sent

Comment: Could you give more information? I am having exact same issue. Little more info will help me solve this issue :)

Comment: @Sisir yeah, so the bytes that were coming from the MediaRecorder were raw, you have to add some kind of encoding to them, in my case .wav to ensure that the bytes are ordered and read in the same way

Comment: I have posted a Q can you take a [look into it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971649/how-to-play-audio-data-stream-coming-via-socket-io-into-a-html5-audio-player)? I think I am doing something else wrong.